# BroadcastReceiver or event when a Calendar Event triggers?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-calendar

Is it possible to set a `BroadcastReceiver` callback or something like that when a calendar event triggers?

Answer (score 0):

Well starting Android 4.0 (ICS) the native calendar app does exist. So there is the standard/public API for that. So no need to test with variety of devices just Android 4.0 and above.

I have started a similar question here:
[BroadcastReceiver for Android Calendar events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217723/broadcastreceiver-for-android-calendar-events)

Cheers,