# BroadcastReceiver for Android Calendar events

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-calendar

I am trying to write a BroadcastReceiver that listens to events like insert, edit, delete to the native android calendar (ICS and above). So whenever one of these events occur the app should be able to at the least know that these events occurred.

Any one has an idea, how to do this or any reference links.

I have written my own broadcasterReceiver class that extends from BroadcastReceiver. Can't figure out the values in the manifest like, currently I have this which is not working:

```
 <receiver
    android:name=".NativeEventChangeReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DELETE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/event"/>
     </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Cheers,

Edit 1:
Does anyone know a proper string for the data tag?, I think this is also required in the intent-filter.

Edit 2:
Any hints about working with ContentObserver?

Comment: wondering why and for what the -1 given to the question...?

Comment: ContentObserver with CalendarContract is not a good idea as we can't listen forever to the changes, so better rely on system events.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finally found the solution after a lot of reading, this may help other finding a similar solution.

In the Manifest, you need to write these lines to be able to capture the changes:

```
<receiver
   android:name=".NativeEventChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Cheers,

Comment: Could you show the code used by the BroadCastReceiver to extract the event data?

Comment: There are many links/thread on reading native calendar events you just need to do that in a service, started by this receiver on its onReceive method.

Comment: Actually I haven't been able to find one. Would you mind sending me a link?

Comment: You can read the official documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Calendars.html  Don't remember the exact link but the official documentation really helped.

Comment: I believe there are no data bundled with that intent, thus, there is no way to find out. You must scan the whole table.

Comment: A little over a year later, this is still a problem. The broadcast intent doesn't have any info on what changed in the calendar provider. Please vote for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55675

Comment: @AliR: I have tried this, It is not workin. IS there any other property need to add. ?

Answer (score 4):

### In addition to the accepted answer:

The intent broadcasted by this code is send when any change is made to the calendar data:

```
<receiver
   android:name=".NativeEventChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Unfortunatly, it is also broadcasted when the device boots, or when the provider is created and there are no Extra's to read what so ever.

**To make your app only handle insertion/deletion of event instances:**

Keep track of the total number of event-instances (as SagiLow points out, this only works on add/delete and does not take updates into account). If it changed, re-validate your data based on the users calendar:

```
public class CalendarChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    private static final String TAG = "CalendarChangedReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Check number of instances
        final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(Enums.Config.USER_CONSTANTS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`enter code here`
        long lastTimeValidated =  prefs.getLong(AppData.LONG_LAST_TIME_VALIDATED, 0);


      int numRowsLastTimeValidated =  prefs.getInt(AppData.INT_NUM_ROWS_LAST_TIME_VALIDATED, 0);
        int numberOfInstances = getNumberOfInstances(lastTimeValidated, context);
        if(numberOfInstances != numRowsLastTimeValidated) {                    

            /* Do somethng here, for instance:
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ValidateCalendarEventsService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);    
            */

        }
    }

    private int getNumberOfInstances(long lastTimeValidated, Context context) {
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();


   beginTime.setTimeInMillis(lastTimeValidated);
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
        endTime.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);//now + 366
        long startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
        long endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();
        Cursor cur = null;
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        // Construct the query with the desired date range.
        Uri.Builder builder = CalendarContract.Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, startMillis);
        ContentUris.appendId(builder, endMillis);
        // Submit the query
        cur = cr.query(builder.build(), null, null, null, null);
        //handle results
        return cur.getCount();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will only work for insertion/deletion, if event was edited it will do nothing

Comment: You should also add a check `if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED")) ` in the broadcastreceiver else it would be called for every broadcast by OS and 3rd party apps.

Comment: The `intent-filter` `action` already filters it for you.