# Detect changes on a native Android calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

In my app, I need to pull events from a native calendar of Android via CalendarContract and do something. Now I need to check whether there are really changes to that calendar to re-pull. Is there such a way on Android?

(On a web app, to check a server, say Google calendar, this is quite simple, I just check the Etag of the calendar to see it is different from my saved ETag. Wondering there is anything equivalent on Android)

Thanks.

**Update**
BroadcastReceiver is not what I need in this case. I don't want my app to constantly track 'pushed' broadcast. I just want to do a quick check whenever I want.

Comment: What you need is a broadcast receiver for calendar changes - there are already answers to that question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BroadcastReceiver for Android Calendar events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217723/broadcastreceiver-for-android-calendar-events)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ContentObserver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/ContentObserver.html) class. You have to implement that class and use the `getContentResolver().registerContentObserver()` method to register the observer.

Comment: tks for your reply, but see my edit of use-case above. I guess when I use registerContentObserver, I have to let a service run to track the change (same as BroadcastReceiver)

Comment: If that is the case, you will need to manually get the eTAG from Calendar API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/