# How to detect android calendar events are edited?

Tags: android, flags, android-calendar, android-event

I already complete contacts synchronization. In contact synchronization I use **VERSION flag** for detecting existing contacts edited by user.

But in calendar synchronization I cannot find VERSION flag.

Then How I detect existing calendars are edited or not?

**VERSION flag not availble in calendar, so what flag used for listen changes in android calendar?**

thanks for your valuable answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I found solution,

I use **DIRTY flag** if any changes happen it automatically **set to 1**.

If **DIRTY=1** then I update edited contents to my own server.

and also reset this DIRTY flag to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/15237331/1009459.
It uses a BroadcastReciever to detect changes made on the calendar provider.

Comment: I don`t know about BroadcastReceiver. I want flags to detect calendar events.