# How to Call back when New Calendar Event added in Phone- Android

Tags: android, calendar, android-manifest, android-calendar

How can I create Listener for Calendar Events, I need to get calback into program when a new event or Updated the existing event in the Calendar in Android.

I have created a BroadCase subClass named `"EventReceiver"` and also added thin Manifest too,

```
              <receiver
                android:name=".EventReceiver"
                android:priority="1000">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
                    <data android:scheme="content"/>
                    <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

But, It is not called when new Calendar event created/Updated.

Hope for a solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BroadcastReceiver for Android Calendar events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217723/broadcastreceiver-for-android-calendar-events)

Comment: Please check previous thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217723/broadcastreceiver-for-android-calendar-events